# I have a Lycamobile sim from the UK. Will it work in Mexico?

Tags: uk, cellphones, mexico, roaming

I have a Lycamobile sim from the UK. Will it work in Mexico?
I'll mostly be communicating with whatsapp and messenger but I had a spare sim lying around so I stuck it in my phone.,

Comment: The roaming details for the UK plans are on [their website](https://www.lycamobile.co.uk/en/rates/)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Lycamobile UK](https://www.lycamobile.co.uk/en/rates/) the sim should work in Mexico, and the rates are as follows (updated September 2019):

[image: Lycamobile UK Mexico roaming]